# MessagePack Plugin updated to latest and seems not working properly

Tags: c#, msgpack

I have a messagepack plugin on my solution with version 1.7.3.7. I updated it to latest version which is 2.4.35. It is successfully upgrade but it is not working as expected

In my old version i have this code

`CompositeResolver.RegisterAndSetAsDefault(new[] { NativeDateTimeResolver.Instance, ContractlessStandardResolver.Instance });`

Looks like `RegisterAndSetAsDefault` is obsolete already on latest version and after couple of hours of research i came up with this new code

```
var resolver = CompositeResolver.Create(NativeDateTimeResolver.Instance, ContractlessStandardResolver.Instance);

MessagePackSerializerOptions mpso = new MessagePackSerializerOptions(resolver);
MessagePackSerializer.DefaultOptions = mpso;`
```

However, when i ran the solution, it couldn't deserialize the object that came from old version

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Any chance you could [edit] your question to share an [mcve] showing an object that, which serialized via the old version, cannot be deserialized using the new version?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the described problem. What do you mean by "couldn't deserialize"? Does it crash, throw exception, produce incorrect data? It is not clear what is the nature of the problem. Can you share a sample of the data you serialize with old version and cannot deserialize with the new one?